# Construct in java, return to beginning of loop when a variable is false

Tags: java, loops

Is there a construct in java that has some code in brackets, like a while loop, but when a variable is set to false, the program returns to the top of the construct?

so if you had

```
var = true
    construct(var = true){
    var = aMethod()
    var = anotherMethod()
    var = aFinalMethod()
}
```

where `aMethod()`, `anotherMethod()` and `aFinalMethod()` are all boolean methods, and if any of them return false, then the loop immediately returns to the top, var is set to true, and the only way to escape is to have all those methods return true.  Is there a construct that does this, or if not, is there a way to achieve it with the constructs in java?

Comment: what value should be set to `var` if all methods returned true?

Comment: There is a `continue` and `break` to jump to next iteration or break the loop and come out of it. May be you are looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html
>
> The continue Statement
>
> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while ,
>   or do-while loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost
>   loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the
>   loop. The following program, ContinueDemo , steps through a String,
>   counting the occurences of the letter "p". If the current character is
>   not a p, the continue statement skips the rest of the loop and
>   proceeds to the next character. If it is a "p", the program increments
>   the letter count.

```
class ContinueDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         String searchMe = "peter piper picked a " + "peck of pickled peppers";
         int max = searchMe.length();
         int numPs = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
             // interested only in p's
             if (searchMe.charAt(i) != 'p')
                 continue;

             // process p's
             numPs++;
         }
         System.out.println("Found " + numPs + " p's in the string.");
         } 
}
```

> Here is the output of this program:
>
> Found 9 p's in the string.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not something like that, so you need to create it by yourself:

```
var = true;
while(var) {
    var = aMethod();
    if (!var)
        continue;
    var = anotherMethod();
    if (!var)
        continue;
    var = aFinalMethod();
    if (!var)
        continue;
    else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html. Here some code that should help:

```
boolean var = true, var1, var2, var3;
while (var) {
    // do some stuff here
    var1 = aMethod()
    var2 = anotherMethod()
    var3 = aFinalMethod()
    var = !(var1 && var2 && var3);
}
```

This will continue to loop until one of your methods sets `var` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure what you need, but here is simple loop, which will try to execute all three methods, till all of them return true:

```
while (!(aMethod() && anotherMethod() && aFinalMethod())) ;
```

so, if at least one method returned false - whole expression will be negated (`!`) and while will continue.

when all methods return true, while will stop

also note, if `aMethod` returned false - `anotherMethod` and `aFinalMethod` will not be executed